# Warning message and error when using CodeValue in Anylogic

Tags: java, anylogic

I am running a model with a method that writes output in a CSV file using the [CodeValue class](https://anylogic.help/api/com/anylogic/engine/database/CodeValue.html). Every time the model runs, I get the message: `Annotation processing got disabled, since it requires a 1.6 compliant JVM`. Most of the time, everything works fine. However, I get this error sometimes: `error during model destruction: truncated class file`. When the error occurs, nothing is written in the CSV files.

AnyLogic 8 Personal Learning Edition 8.7.7
Build: 8.7.7.202109242327 x64

```
Annotation processing got disabled, since it requires a 1.6 compliant JVM
Exception during discrete event execution:
Truncated class file
----------
1. ERROR in /fertility_bmi/Expression_1_xjal.java (at line 1)
    package fertility_bmi;
    ^
The type com.anylogic.engine.markup.PedFlowStatistics cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
----------
2. ERROR in /fertility_bmi/Expression_1_xjal.java (at line 43)
    import com.anylogic.engine.markup.PedFlowStatistics;
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The import com.anylogic.engine.markup.PedFlowStatistics cannot be resolved
----------
2 problems (2 errors)
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:877)
    at com.anylogic.engine.internal.q.b.j(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.internal.q.b.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.internal.q.a.j(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.internal.o.b.j(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Utilities.executeExpression(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Utilities.executeExpression(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.database.CodeValue.execute(Unknown Source)
    at fertility_bmi.ExportOutput.getValues(ExportOutput.java:144)
    at fertility_bmi.Main.executeActionOf(Main.java:981)
    at com.anylogic.engine.EventTimeout.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.j(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.runFast(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.runFast(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.ExperimentParamVariation$j.n(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.f$j.run(Unknown Source)
Annotation processing got disabled, since it requires a 1.6 compliant JVM
----------
1. ERROR in /fertility_bmi/Expression_1_xjal.java (at line 1)
    package fertility_bmi;
    ^
The type com.anylogic.engine.Engine cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
----------
1 problem (1 error)
Exception during discrete event execution:
Truncated class file
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:877)
    at com.anylogic.engine.internal.q.b.j(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.internal.q.b.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.internal.q.a.j(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.internal.o.b.j(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Utilities.executeExpression(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Utilities.executeExpression(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.database.CodeValue.execute(Unknown Source)
    at fertility_bmi.ExportOutput.getValues(ExportOutput.java:144)
    at fertility_bmi.Main.executeActionOf(Main.java:981)
    at com.anylogic.engine.EventTimeout.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.j(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.runFast(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.runFast(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.ExperimentParamVariation$j.n(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.f$j.run(Unknown Source)
Annotation processing got disabled, since it requires a 1.6 compliant JVM
Annotation processing got disabled, since it requires a 1.6 compliant JVM
Annotation processing got disabled, since it requires a 1.6 compliant JVM
Annotation processing got disabled, since it requires a 1.6 compliant JVM
Annotation processing got disabled, since it requires a 1.6 compliant JVM
Annotation processing got disabled, since it requires a 1.6 compliant JVM
Error:
Error in the model during iteration 68
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in the model during iteration 68
    at com.anylogic.engine.ExperimentParamVariation$j.n(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.f$j.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas on how to deal with this?

Comment: Probably because it could not use annotation to generate the code.  You should try a JVM that is greater than 1.6.

Comment: Please confirm your version of AnyLogic

Comment: thanks, @Jaco-BenVosloo. I added it to the question.